# Is `.` destination for the ADD/COPY dockerfile commands resolved with respect to WORKDIR?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build

Dockerfile ADD/COPY commands support the destination value to be a relative (to WORKDIR) path or an absolute path. Also, the source value is always the build context.

However, if the destination is specified as `.`, then is it resolved with respect to the WORKDIR (and does it default to the root (C:) if WORKDIR is not specified)?

Comment: Can you please check if it answers your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. `.` will consider the current directory as WORKDIR(if it's specified) and if not, then by default it will consider to `/`  or `root` directory as `.`

Answer (score 1):

```
WORKDIR app
```

this statement creates a folder named app and moves to that directory which is `app`

```
COPY <host> <container>
```

- *host:* relative location where the docker file exists.
- *container:* location in the container which will be relative to where you are presently in the container. You initially start in the root directory of the container but when you use `RUN cd` or `WORKDIR` on dockerfile then the location would be relative to where you are presently in the container.